# how to handle event dispatching in easeljs 0.7.0

Tags: javascript, events, easeljs

been looking at easeljs and seem to be confused about what's the best way to go about event delegation. Here's what I'm trying:

```
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

    var txt1 = new createjs.Text('Test With Hit Area', '24px Arial', '#0000ff');
    txt1.x = 50;
    txt1.y = 50;
    console.log('txt1', txt1);
    var hit = new createjs.Shape();
    hit.graphics.beginFill('#000000').drawRect(500, 50, txt1.getMeasuredWidth(), txt1.getMeasuredHeight())
    txt1.hitArea = hit;
    // neither seem to work with a hitArea
    // txt1.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    txt1.on('click', handleClick);

    var txt2 = new createjs.Text('Test Without Hit Area', '24px Arial', '#0000ff');
    txt2.x = 50;
    txt2.y = 80;
    console.log('txt2', txt2);
    // both addEventListener() and on() work fine without hit area
    // txt2.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    txt2.on('click', handleClick);


    stage.addChild(txt1, txt2);
    stage.update();
}

function handleClick() {
    console.log('clicked', this);
}

init();
```

I've created a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate my attempts here: http://jsfiddle.net/brrWn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hitArea will automatically align itself with the Shape, so you should set the x & y of the rectangle to 0,0.

```
hit.graphics.beginFill('#000000')
    .drawRect(0, 0, txt1.getMeasuredWidth(), txt1.getMeasuredHeight())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/brrWn/2/

I turned on mouseover and set the cursor, which makes it easier to visualize the hitArea.
Cheers.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for this Lanny. I would have never found that out on my own. OOC, do you know if this is in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: Yep, this is documented in "hitArea" property - although maybe it could be clearer. http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_hitArea